# MySQL date between won't get desired result

Tags: mysql, sql

i've got a weird case.
It's annoyingly easy to solve but I can't figure it out.

My goal was storing the history of some racing drivers' transfers.

I have this table with example data:
table's name is `contratti` (contracts)

```
id | start | end | pilot_id | team_id | role
1 | 2019-09-05 | 2019-09-17 | 1 | 10 | 1
2 | 2019-09-17 | 2020-04-01 | 1 | 3 | 1
3 | 2020-04-02 | NULL | 1 | 9 | 2
```

Basically it contains every pilot&team contract with his start and finish date, and other minor details.

If the `end` field is set to null, then it means that there's no end date published yet.

My goal is to get through a query (with a `pilot_id` and a date) the corresponding `team_id` of that time.

eg: given `pilot_id` as 1, and date as `2020-05-14`, system would return `9`.

eg2: given `pilot_id` as 1, and date as `2019-12-25`, system would return `3`.

I know it is fairly easy to do, but it's about an hour i'm trying and I can't solve this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need an `or` comparison:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.pilot_id = :pilot_id and
      :date >= t.start and
      (:date <= t.end or t.end is null)
```

Comment: Thanks gordon, i basically did the same previously, but probably got some wrong/messed up syntax.